# How do controller actions get mapped to routes under the hood?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, controller, asp.net-core-middleware

I've been trying to dive deep into the [aspnetcore](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore) repository to try to understand how controller actions get mapped onto routes within the middleware. To me it seems like black magic. I see that `UseEndpoints` and `MapControllers` seem to perform these functions, but I'm quickly getting lost in how complex the code is. Could anyone point me in a direction to understand how controller actions get mapped to routes under the hood?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cr

Comment: Every controller action / page handler will have a matching `ActionDescriptor`. So I think you could start from the middle ... here? https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8b30d862de6c9146f466061d51aa3f1414ee2337/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.cs#L87.

Comment: I would suggest you to start with the new project to begin with if you are new, then it would be better to go through this kind of repository. Try to create a new controller , then see how the [request routed to your controller and how it produce the view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)... so that you can get into this repo quickly

Comment: Thanks @Chetan and @Md Farid Uddin Kiron, but I already understand how to use them. I'm wondering how they controllers get processed to be consumed by the `UseEndpoints` middleware. Do you have any suggestions on where to go to learn how this processing happens under the hood? Forgive me if I'm not understandding you.

Comment: @RyanClements Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman is on the path of what I'm looking for. I was looking today in the source code and saw that internally, data source classes are constructed, added to the DI, system, then used by the EndpointMiddleware class somehow. More details on how that works would be ideal.

Comment: just anything that will help me understand how requests are mapped to controller methods under the hood. I already understand how to use `UseEndpoints`, but I'm just curious how its implemented and the source code is pretty complex.

Comment: As mentioned above, that would be helpful

Comment: I have shared the link below the answer which help you to know more details about your concern, it will escalate your thought. Let me know if you need any futher assistance.

Comment: It's very complex :). How far down the rabbit hole do you want to go? https://youtu.be/8k0OKeGsWTg?t=1202 explains endpoint routing pretty well

Answer (score 0):

Well I got your point, let me explain you, there are lot of process in between, many  `delegates` works from `controller` to `middleware` process accomplishment.

You could see this diagram to understand the full process steps, how the full mechanism works under the hood.

***Asp.net Process Flow:***

[image]

Additionally I would suggest you to to go through our official document below which eventually make stronger your understanding.

1. [Asp.net core MVC pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#what-is-the-mvc-pattern)
2. [Middleware deeper understanding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#middleware-order)

Hope it will help to get started with nice guidelines.